# Doesn't run this commands on mautic cron job

Tags: cron, mautic

Hi guys i have the next problem(sorry for my english):

I want to executate a command in Mautic cron job, i put the next comands:

> */1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /apps/mautic/htdocs/app/console  mautic:segments:update
>
> */1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /apps/mautic/htdocs/app/console mautic:campaigns:update
>
> */1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /apps/mautic/htdocs/app/console mautic:campaigns:trigger

I try a lot of things but no one of them work, like:

```
*/1 * * * *  root /usr/local/bin/php /apps/mautic/htdocs/app/console  mautic:segments:update
```

or

```
*/1 * * * * bitnami php /apps/mautic/htdocs/app/console  mautic:segments:update
```

But i don't know what fail's,if it's the user name,the route to php,the comand,if they doesn't have permission...

If i put this manually work perfectly

```
php /apps/mautic/htdocs/app/console  mautic:segments:update
```

ty so much

Comment: can you locate the php by this command? `which php`

Comment: Manually yes but i think it doesnt work on the crontab.But i dont know the route of the php,can u help me?

Comment: can you type this command `which php` in terminal and give the output here?

Comment: it return me this: /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php.   But i put the command in the crontab and doesn't work too: */1 * * * * root /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php apps/mautic/htdocs/app/console mautic:segments:update

Comment: You may need to check the crontab syntax. It composes by two parts, five fields for day, date, time and followed by command. how about `*/1 * * * * /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php apps/mautic/htdocs/app/console mautic:segments:update`?

Comment: The comand i put manually to work is: php /apps/mautic/htdocs/app/console  mautic:segments:update.  So what is your recomendation?

Comment: Apparently you are using incorrect path of php `/usr/local/bin/php`. Replaced the correct path `/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php` should solve the problem. You are no need to add username before the command.

Comment: `which php` helps you locate the path of **php** program

Comment: i know what you are trying to tell me but if php run like a program I think I don't need to put the real route on the crontab no?

Comment: crontab no sense of the path, so you need to add the full path of crontab. You can run the **php** program, because your user have setup the environment, you can run `echo $PATH` on terminal, when bash lookup the **php** program, it will search through all the paths defined in your user environment variable $PATH.

Comment: okay finally it's like: */1 * * * * /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /home/bitnami/apps/mautic/htdocs/app/console mautic:segments:update .  But still not working,can be probably cause the second part of the comand don't read it like a only one comand?

Comment: Can you dump and check the program output? You may change the crontab command to `*/1 * * * * /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /home/bitnami/apps/mautic/htdocs/app/console mautic:segments:update 2>&1 >> /tmp/output.log` and check the log file.

Comment: it returns:Failed to lock /opt/bitnami/apps/mautic/htdocs/app/cache/prod/../run/sf.mautic-segments-update.5415eaf7823c0a036b252ba8a9f1f4065263e1c60a23cacf6b5851144245b8c9.lock
.
Script in progress. Can force execution by using --force.
Failed to lock /opt/bitnami/apps/mautic/htdocs/app/cache/prod/../run/sf.mautic-segments-update.5415eaf7823c0a036b252ba8a9f1f4065263e1c60a23cacf6b5851144245b8c9.lock
.
Script in progress. Can force execution by using --force.

Comment: it can be because i dont use sudo? if i put sudo at the start of the command¿?

Comment: probably don't have enough permission to access the folder. you may need to check the user executed the command has enough permission to access the cache folder

Comment: you might need to add the cron job to root user. sudo won't work in cron job.

Comment: Man it finally work! is for the sudo: */1 * * * * sudo /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /home/bitnami/apps/mautic/htdocs/app/console mautic:segments:update.  So ty for all the help

Comment: Please mark me as a accepted answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether the path of the **php** program correct. You can check the the full path of the **php** program in terminal output by this command:

```
which php
```

To create a cron job, should always use the full path of the program. The crontab default environment is not like the logged in user. The program may not be found  if the path is not defined to the crontab environment.

The crontab syntax composed of two parts, datetime to execute & command to be executed. User is not required to add before the command.

```
*     *     *   *    *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of        month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it turns out that my root user wasn't enabled, therefore there wasn't any way for the system to log in with a root account to perform the cronjobs.

I just made sure that I had my root account enabled with a valid pasword.

Check that by typing:

```
sudo passwd --status root
```

If this is the case, just try to change your root password

```
 sudo passwd root
```